# Why does the proof of the weak Nullstellensatz require we define an isomorphism $\phi:k\to k[x_1,...,x_n]\to k[x_1,...,x_n]/m$ through composition?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The proof of the weak Nullstellensatz (every maximal ideal has the form $(x_1 - a_1, \dots, x_n - a_n)$) goes as follows: let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. We define $\phi$ to be the composition of the natural embedding and natural projection as such: $\phi:k \to k[x_1,\dots,x_n] \to k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak m$, which is clearly an injection. Then, by Zariski's lemma $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak m$ is a finite field extension of $k$. But since $k$ is algebraically closed, this means $k$ is isomorphic to $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak m$, and therefore, $\phi$ cannot be a proper injection. Therefore, $\phi$ is an isomorphism, from which we argue that there are $a_i \in k$ satisfying $\phi(a_i)= x_i + \mathfrak m = a_i + \mathfrak m$, so $x_i - a_i \in \mathfrak m$ completing the proof.

**My question is**: since we only need some injection that takes $a_i \in k$ to $a_i + \mathfrak m \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak m$ to obtain the isomorphism we desire, why do we need to specifically use the above composition? Can't we simply define $\phi:k \to k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak m:a_i \mapsto a_i+\mathfrak m$, i.e., a direct map from $k$ to $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak m$ that does not go through $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$?

Comment: What you define is exactly that composition, isn't it...?

Comment: Of course we can, this is the same map. I guess some just think it just looks a bit more clear if we take the composition of the two natural maps that we use all the time, instead of defining a new map directly. After all, $k$ is not a subfield of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$, but only up to an embedding. So whether you mention it or not, this composition always goes through $k[x_1,...,x_n]$.

Comment: @Pedro I might be confused here, but I think the map I define doesn't go through $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. I don't understand why the proof specifically mentions the composition of maps.

Comment: @Mark oh, I posted my last comment exactly at the same time as your comment. I see, that clears things up. Thank you very much.

Comment: @shintuku Well, it does go through $k[x_*]$, since it is the composition $\lambda \longmapsto \lambda$ sending a scalar to a constant polynomial, with the projection to the quotient.

Comment: @Pedro I see, thank you!